# Hextoraw() not working with IN clause while using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to update certain rows in my oracle DB using id which is of RAW(255). 
Sample ids 0BF3957A016E4EBCB68809E6C2EA8B80, 1199B9F29F0A46F486C052669854C2F8...

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTempalte;

private static final String UPDATE_SUB_STATUS = "update SUBSCRIPTIONS set status = :status, modified_date = systimestamp where id in (:ids)";


public void saveSubscriptionsStatus(List<String> ids, String status) {

        MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        List<String> idsHexToRaw = new ArrayList<>();
        String temp =  new String();
        for (String id : ids) {
            temp = "hextoraw('" + id + "')";
            idsHexToRaw.add(temp);
        }
        paramSource.addValue("ids", idsHexToRaw);
        paramSource.addValue("status", status);
        jdbcTempalte.update(*UPDATE_SUB_STATUS*, paramSource);
    }
```

This above block of code is executing without any error but the updates are not reflected to the db, while **if I skip using hextoraw() and just pass the list of ids it works fine and also updates the data in table**. see below code

```
public void saveSubscriptionsStatus(List<String> ids, String status) {

        MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();]
        paramSource.addValue("ids", ids);
        paramSource.addValue("status", status);
        jdbcTempalte.update(UPDATE_SUB_STATUS, paramSource);
    }
```

this code works fine and updates the table, but since i am **not using hextoraw() it scans the full table for updation which I don't want since i have created indexes**. So using hextoraw() will use index for scanning the table but it is not updating the values which is kind of weird.

Comment: updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution myself by trying all the different combinations :

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTempalte;

public void saveSubscriptionsStatus(List<String> ids, String status) {

    String UPDATE_SUB_STATUS = "update SUBSCRIPTIONS set status = :status, modified_date = systimestamp where id in (";
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    String subQuery = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
        String temp = "id" + i;
        paramSource.addValue(temp, ids.get(i));
        subQuery = subQuery + "hextoraw(:" + temp + "), ";
    }
    subQuery = subQuery.substring(0, subQuery.length() - 2);
    UPDATE_SUB_STATUS = UPDATE_SUB_STATUS + subQuery + ")";
    paramSource.addValue("status", status);
    jdbcTempalte.update(UPDATE_SUB_STATUS, paramSource);
}
```

What this do is create a query with all the ids to hextoraw as id0, id1, id2...... and also added this values in the MapSqlParameterSource instance and then this worked fine and it also used the index for updating my table.

1. After running my new function  the query look like : **update
   SUBSCRIPTIONS set status = :status, modified_date = systimestamp
   where id in (hextoraw(:id0), hextoraw(:id1), hextoraw(:id2)...)**
2. MapSqlParameterSource instance looks like : **{("id0", "randomUUID"),
   ("id1", "randomUUID"), ("id2", "randomUUID").....}**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing string manipulation, Convert the list to List of ByteArray

```
List<byte[]> productGuidByteList = stringList.stream().map(item -> GuidHelper.asBytes(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
parameters.addValue("productGuidSearch", productGuidByteList);

public static byte[] asBytes(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return bb.array();
}
```